# inserting values into table with multiple level parent child values

Tags: sql, insert

I have a table that has the following columns:

[metatableid]
  ,[metagroup]
  ,[metaname]
  ,[parent]
  ,[owner]

Within that table there is a hierarchy of values with a parent/child relationships.

I need to insert 23 values into the table  multiple times where the parent = a certain value. And take the current metatableid and make it the parent

I have a table that just contains list names I need to add the 23 values in that table as a sub category

The hierarchy should look like this

```
metatableid       metagroup           metaname         parent    owner
11159             1000                Marketing Lists  0         NULL
11160             1000                Sponsors         11159     NULL
11161             1000                Byrd, Jackie     11160     NULL
```

The first row is the main category the second is a sub of the main and third is a sub of that one.

I need to add the 23 values as a sub of the metatableid 11161 and then do it again for 90 more rows that are part of that sub category?

Other then doing it one at a time is there a faster way help?

Answer (score 0):

If your additional rows are in a table somewhere, and assuming that MetatableID is an autonumber/identity field, you could make an insert statement similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO metatable 
SELECT 1000 as metagroup, metaname, 11161 as parent, NULL as owner
FROM datasource;
```

Comment: What I was hoping for was something a little more complex. I know I can do that what i would like to do is a select query that outputs the parentid and all the values basically. some type of a loop that will give me an output of the 23 values in the table and also the parentid 23 times for each sub.

Comment: Unless you say what RDBMS you're using, and give a lot more detail as to how these other values are stored, that's probably the best anyone can do for you.